# PCB via array for "better" heat dissipation

Tags: pcb-design, heat, thermal, pcb-layers, ground-plane

My two PCB mount power supplies are getting quite hot (temp 60 to 70 degrees). Max temp of the power supply is 90 degrees. I cannot use external heatsinks due to space constraints.

Input voltage is 50V DC, the output voltage is 5V at 3.2A and the other has the same input with a 12V 3A output. The output track width is 3mm wide for both power supplies.

I have read about thermal via arrays in order to dissipate heat more effectively. So I made a polygon in red (top layer) that extends over both power supplies and it is the ground plane. The bottom layer (green layer) is also the ground layer. The via drill size is 0.4mm and the outer diameter is 0.8mm. The via goes from the top layer and is connected to the ground plane at the bottom.

[image]

Or is it better to make two separate polygons as shown below? Is the via size correct

[image]

Comment: That may reduce the temp rise a few 'C but you need 1W / sq.in. with free convection

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 any other ways I can achieve the 1W/sq.in heat dissipation?

Comment: What is your 2x sided present copper area and Pd dissipation and temp rise. In deg 'C/W/sq.in.?  you need to increase air flow or increase the emissive surface area or reduce losses.

Comment: Some of the heat is coupled through the pins, and only 1/3 of the pins connect to the copper pours.  Is there enough room to mount a 40mm fan?